# Patching a classpath when running Surefire tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, classloader, surefire

We are developing code in the context of a legacy Java application that heavily uses static members and system properties, expecting files in various locations on the disk. The builds are run in Maven.

We are trying to allow unit testing of our code without having to deploy, configure and start the whole application. I have managed to do this by patching a small number of classes in the framework, providing my own variants of the relevant source files in Maven's test sources in `src/test/java`.

As a next step I would like to make this patch re-usable by providing a JAR file that can be pulled in as a test dependency on any project that develops a part of the larger application. I would like to deploy this via our normal binary repository.

Surefire offers an option to set `<additionalClasspathElements>`, but according to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) this works only with absolute paths and will add the dependency at the end of the class path.

In theory ordering the project dependencies correctly could work, but I cannot find any documentation on how that order works across multiple scopes. I would need Maven to guarantee that my `test` dependency is loaded before the `runtime` ones.

What is a reliable way of patching classes for a Surefire run by using a JAR pulled via Maven's dependency resolution mechanisms?

Comment: It seems you have already solved your issue. I would have said getting the jar together would be the pain. If you want to use a non maven binary repo, heres your options: http://maven.apache.org/scm/scms-overview.html

Comment: @AnthonyJClink: how have I solved my issue? Am I missing something? Regarding the repository: your list is about source code management, we use http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/ to manage our binary repositories.

Comment: I missed the part about the static members... The only real way to avoid that is not to load the code, or you could depend on a non legacy injection but that would require some hacking. (like guice or springs request static injection).   Or if the peices are large enough that you can simply stub out the unimportant code and replace the module... but again.. hacky... :(

Comment: I am not in a position to change the legacy code - that's why I am patching things on the classpath when running tests.